# Copy a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to take a copy of a DataGridView.

```
Public Sub CopyDataView(ByVal inGrid As DataGridView,
                        ByVal inPrintHiddenCols As Boolean)
    DataGridView1 = inGrid
```

I then alter the configuration of DataGridView1 then do:

```
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    DataGridView1.Visible = True
```

The problem I'm having is done to DataGridView1 and only the Original grid is changed and refreshed.  This is despite the fact that the original grid is passed ByVal.

I've tried processing the passed grid, column, by column, row by row, but I get the error

```
"Provided column already belongs to the DataGridView control"
```

The DataGridView1 is initialized

```
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.AutoSize = True
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False

            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In inGrid.Columns
            If col.Width = 0 Or _
               col.Displayed = False And _
               Not (inPrintHiddenCols) Then
                SkipCells.Add(col.Index)
            Else
                Dim c As New DataGridViewColumn
                c = col
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(c)  ' <----------------------
                ColWidth_CSV.Add(modFunctions.GetWidthOfText(col.Width, f))
            End If
        Next
```

on the first column to be added. I've searched all the instances of this error, but the only solutions say "Copy the DataSource", there is no DataSource, this is a generated table. I can't find a way to transform the DataGridView data into a DataSource either.

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you just wanting the data from that grid thats passed?

Comment: DGV Columns are Components. the line `c = col` means `c` is no longer a NEW column, but refers to the column which *already* exists in the source. So you cant add `c` to the dest DGV because it already belongs to the source DGV in the guise of `col`

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing this:

```
Dim c As New DataGridViewColumn
c = col.Clone
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(c)
```

I seems to work fine now.